# Error of "No implicit ordering defined for U" where a trait which has extended Ordered

Tags: scala, traits

After creating a ScalaIDE Worksheet named `test.WsTemp`, I wrote the code below and am receiving three errors for a single line in trait `Enum`:

1. Diverging implicit expansion for type `scala.math.Ordering[U]` starting with method ordered in trait `LowPriorityOrderingImplicits`
2. No implicit `Ordering` defined for `U`
3. Not enough arguments for method sorted: `(implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[U])List[U]`, Unspecified value parameter `ord`.

Why isn't this working since it's obvious `Val` extends `Ordered[Val]`?

```
object WsTemp {
  trait Val extends Ordered[Val] {
    val id: Int
    val name: String
    final def compare(that: Val) = this.id - that.id
    override def toString: String = name
  }

  trait Enum[U <: Val] {
    protected def init: Set[U]
    val all = init
    val allOrdered = all.toList.sorted       // <-- Receiving error here
    val byId = all.map(x => (x.id, x)).toMap
    val byName = all.map(x => (x.name, x)).toMap

    def apply(id: Int) = byId.get(id)
    def apply(name: String) = byName.get(name)
  }

  sealed class Value(val id: Int, val name: String) extends Val
  object Suit extends Enum[Value] {
    override def init: Set[Value] = //Set()
      Set(
          new Value(0, "Spade")
        , new Value(1, "Club")
        , new Value(2, "Diamond")
        , new Value(3, "Heart")
      )
    val Spade = Suit.byId(0)
    val Club = Suit.byId(1)
    val Diamond = Suit.byId(2)
    val Heart = Suit.byId(3)
  }

  val all = Suit.all
  val allOrdered = Suit.allOrdered
  val byId = Suit.byId
  val byName = Suit.byName
  val spade = Suit.Spade
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ordering` and `Ordered` are both invariant , so the fact that `U` is a sub-type of `Val` (as expressed by the relation `U <: Val`) does not imply that `Ordering[Val]` can be used as an `Ordering[U]`.
So even though the fact that `Val` extends `Ordered[Val]` means that you implicitly get an `Ordering[Val]`, this means nothing regarding `Ordering[U]`.

So the compiler is right to complain that it cannot find an implicit value of type `Ordering[U]` (which is required by the call to `sorted`).

The prolbem is easy to illustrate with a small code snippet that mimics what happens with `Ordered` and `Ordering`:

```
object WsTemp {
  trait MyOrdered[T]

  trait MyOrdering[T]
  object MyOrdering {
    implicit def toOrdering[A <% MyOrdered[A]]: MyOrdering[A] = new MyOrdering[A]{}
  }

  trait Val extends MyOrdered[Val]

  def test[T](implicit ord: MyOrdering[T]) {}

  trait Enum[U <: Val] {
    def callTest() { test[U] }
  }
}
```

Which produces the following error:

```
<console>:20: error: could not find implicit value for parameter ord: WsTemp.MyOrdering[U]
           def callTest() { test[U] }
```

But if you make `MyOrdered` and `MyOrdering` covariant, this compiles fine:

```
trait MyOrdered[+T]      
trait MyOrdering[+T]
...
```

Obviously, you cannot change scala's `Ordering` nor `Ordered` to make them invariant.

---

Now, one way to solve your problem is to arrange your code so that `Val` does not extend `Ordered[Val]`, but instead extends `Ordered[X]` where `X` is the actual type that you want to have an `Ordering` for (here, `X` = `U`). This can be achieved with *F-bounded polymorphism*:

```
trait Val[Self<:Val[Self]] extends Ordered[Self] {
  //...
}

trait Enum[U <: Val[U]] {
  //...
}

sealed class Value(val id: Int, val name: String) extends Val[Value]
//...
```

`U` is now a sub-type of `Val[U]`, which is a sub-type of `Ordered[U]` (as opposed to a sub-type of `Ordered[Val]` as before), and so you now implicitly get an `Ordering[U]`, which is (implicitly) passed to `sorted`. Problem solved.

Comment: Jean-Gilles: Tysvm for answering. I have read and re-read your answer and still don't understand it. And attempting Google up references to Self in your second code section haven't turned anything up. So, I am sensing that "Self" is a type, like U?

Comment: BTW, I got the first part of your answer (the first section). It was just the first line of your second answer that has my Scala newbie brain confused.

Comment: Just round this article at Twitter describing "F-bounded Polymorphism" thing you used: http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/advanced-types.html#fbounded  - so it's a self-referential type, fascinating!

Answer (score 1):

As Régis Jean-Gilles said, "Ordering and Ordered are both invariant , so the fact that U is a sub-type of Val (as expressed by the relation U <: Val) does not imply that Ordering[Val] can be used as an Ordering[U]. So even though the fact that Val extends Ordered[Val] means that you implicitly get an Ordering[Val], this means nothing regarding Ordering[U]."

A very simple way to fix this is to specify the type to use for the sorted method.  Replace:

```
  val allOrdered = all.toList.sorted
```

with:

```
  val allOrdered = all.toList.sorted[Val]
```